# How do I adapt this program to comply with the online judge?

Tags: java

I'm solving UVA's Edit Step Ladders on an uva sub-site named programming-challenges.com, but since I didn't get at all the format in which I'm supposed to test-input I simply took their sample input, put it into a text file and tested my code from there. Like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Levenshtein {
    private static int minimum(int a, int b, int c) {
        if(a<=b && a<=c)
            return a;
        if(b<=a && b<=c)
            return b;
        return c;
    }

public static int computeLevenshteinDistance(String str1, String str2) {
    return computeLevenshteinDistance(str1.toCharArray(),
                                      str2.toCharArray());
}

private static int computeLevenshteinDistance(char [] str1, char [] str2) {
    int [][]distance = new int[str1.length+1][str2.length+1];

    for(int i=0;i<=str1.length;i++)
            distance[i][0]=i;

    for(int j=0;j<=str2.length;j++)
        distance[0][j]=j;

    for(int i=1;i<=str1.length;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=str2.length;j++)
            distance[i][j]= minimum(distance[i-1][j]+1,
                                    distance[i][j-1]+1,
                                    distance[i-1][j-1]+
                                    ((str1[i-1]==str2[j-1])?0:1));

    return distance[str1.length][str2.length];
}

public static void main(String args[]){

ArrayList<String> theWords = new ArrayList<String>();

try {

        String ruta="entradaLevenshtein.txt";
        File myFile = new File (ruta);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line = null;

        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            theWords.add(line);
        }



        reader.close();
    }

    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
 {}
 // todo esto sólo para iniciar el arreglo
 // ahora vienen las llamadas a Levenstein y las comparaciones

 int maxEdit=0;
 int actualEdit=0;

 int wordsIndex1 =0, wordsIndex2=0;


 while (wordsIndex1<= theWords.size())
 {
  while (wordsIndex2<= theWords.size()-1){
     actualEdit=computeLevenshteinDistance(theWords.get(wordsIndex1),theWords.get(wordsIndex2));
     if (actualEdit>maxEdit){maxEdit=actualEdit;}
     wordsIndex2++;
  }
 wordsIndex1++;

 }

 System.out.println(maxEdit+1);
}



}
```

my input file being:

```
cat
dig
dog
fig
fin
fine
fog
log
wine
```

I'm supposed to make the code comply to the following pattern, thing is..I don't get where this thing is capturing its String:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Modelo implements Runnable{
    static String ReadLn(int maxLength){  // utility function to read from stdin,
                                          // Provided by Programming-challenges, edit for style only
        byte line[] = new byte [maxLength];
        int length = 0;
        int input = -1;
        try{
            while (length < maxLength){//Read untill maxlength
                input = System.in.read();
                if ((input < 0) || (input == '\n')) break; //or untill end of line ninput
                line [length++] += input;
            }

            if ((input < 0) && (length == 0)) return null;  // eof
            return new String(line, 0, length);
        }catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) // entry point from OS
    {
        Modelo myWork = new Modelo();  // Construct the bootloader
        myWork.run();            // execute
    }

    public void run() {
        new myStuff().run();
    }
}
class myStuff implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try
        {

        /// PLACE YOUR JAVA CODE HERE




        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("A Exception was generated");
        }
    }

    // You can insert more classes here if you want.
}
```

Why should I place it where it says //place your code here and not here??

```
 try{
                    while (length < maxLength){//Read untill maxlength
                        input = System.in.read();
                        if ((input < 0) || (input == '\n')) break; //or untill end of line input
                        line [length++] += input;

}
```

How do I manipulate the input??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea here is to write your program in the `myStuff` class, where it will be called in the `run()` method. From the `run()` method, you can use `Modelo.ReadLn()` to get your input.