# Problem processing input for online judge

Tags: java

This is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929001/how-do-i-adapt-this-program-to-comply-with-the-online-judge)

I'm solving UVA's Edit Step Ladders and trying to make the online judge comply with my answer.

I have used the method ReadLn() to adapt my textfile-reading program to this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class LevenshteinParaElJuez implements Runnable{
    static String ReadLn(int maxLength){  // utility function to read from stdin,
                                          // Provided by Programming-challenges, edit for style only
        byte line[] = new byte [maxLength];
        int length = 0;
        int input = -1;
        try{
            while (length < maxLength){//Read untill maxlength
                input = System.in.read();
                if ((input < 0) || (input == '\n')) break; //or untill end of line ninput
                line [length++] += input;
            }

            if ((input < 0) && (length == 0)) return null;  // eof
            return new String(line, 0, length);
        }catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) // entry point from OS
    {
        LevenshteinParaElJuez myWork = new LevenshteinParaElJuez();  // Construct the bootloader
        myWork.run();            // execute
    }

    public void run() {
        new myStuff().run();
    }
}
class myStuff implements Runnable{
    public void run(){

        ArrayList<String> theWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {

        /// PLACE YOUR JAVA CODE HERE

        String leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);

        //System.out.println("lo leido fue "+leido);

        while (!leido.equals(" ")){
        theWords.add(leido);
        leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);
        }


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("El programa genero una excepcion");
        }


        int maxEdit=0;
        int actualEdit=0;

     int wordsIndex1 =0, wordsIndex2=0;


     while (wordsIndex1<= theWords.size())
     {
      while (wordsIndex2<= theWords.size()-1){
         actualEdit=Levenshtein.computeLevenshteinDistance(theWords.get(wordsIndex1),theWords.get(wordsIndex2));
         if (actualEdit>maxEdit){maxEdit=actualEdit;}
         wordsIndex2++;
      }
     wordsIndex1++;

     }

     System.out.println(maxEdit+1);



    }


}
class Levenshtein {
    private static int minimum(int a, int b, int c) {
        if(a<=b && a<=c)
            return a;
        if(b<=a && b<=c)
            return b;
        return c;
    }

    public static int computeLevenshteinDistance(String str1, String str2) {
        return computeLevenshteinDistance(str1.toCharArray(),
                                          str2.toCharArray());
    }

    private static int computeLevenshteinDistance(char [] str1, char [] str2) {
        int [][]distance = new int[str1.length+1][str2.length+1];

        for(int i=0;i<=str1.length;i++)
                distance[i][0]=i;

        for(int j=0;j<=str2.length;j++)
            distance[0][j]=j;

        for(int i=1;i<=str1.length;i++)
            for(int j=1;j<=str2.length;j++)
                distance[i][j]= minimum(distance[i-1][j]+1,
                                        distance[i][j-1]+1,
                                        distance[i-1][j-1]+
                                        ((str1[i-1]==str2[j-1])?0:1));

        return distance[str1.length][str2.length];
    }


}
```

I'm supposed to read the whole of the online judge's input as it were written via keyboard, but when I run the above program I can't make it stop reading. It goes something like:

```
abc
cba
aba
cca
```

without being able to stop the console reading. How do I get around this?? I suspect the problem is in my loop's conditional:

```
String leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);

            //System.out.println("lo leido fue "+leido);

            while (!leido.equals(" ")){
            theWords.add(leido);
            leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);
            }
```

I have also used:

```
while (!leido.equals(null)){
        theWords.add(leido);
        leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);
        }
```

and gotten stuck as well.

Edit: the declaration was actually:

```
while (leido != null)){
        theWords.add(leido);
        leido=LevenshteinParaElJuez.ReadLn(100);
        }
```

I don't get why it's failing. I want the reading of input via keyboard to stop when the first blank line is entered.

Edit: thanks to rodion's answer, the ReadLn method is now changed to:

```
if ((input < 0) || (length == 0)) return null;  // eof
```

instead of:

```
if ((input < 0) && (length == 0)) return null;  // eof
```

Now, it's reading two blank space before producing the integer output. How can I change it just to read one?

Comment: I don't understand the question...do you only want to read one word at a time?  If so, why do you have the loop? If not, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want the program to stop reading when I input a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the input will not be <0 when it reaches the line that returns null, so do:

```
while (leido.length() != 0) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped (!leido.equals(null)), I actually used while (leido != null)) like you said and got stuck reading. I want the reading to stop when a blank line enters

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if I understand your problem correctly. If you merely want your program to stop reading from the console, you can "close" the console by hitting Ctrl+D (Linux) or Ctrl+Z (Windows). This causes System.in.read() to return -1, so that ReadLn method would return null.

Check for null as Nathaniel suggested.

**Edit**: (based on your comment)

The problem is with this condition in the ReadLn method

```
if ((input < 0) && (length == 0)) return null;
```

If you enter a blank line, length will be 0, input will be > 0 though (whatever your system uses to denote a newline).
If you change it to

```
if ((input < 0) || (length == 0)) return null;
```

the method will return null if either the input stream is closed or a blank line is entered.**strong text**

Comment: I want the program to stop reading from console when it gets a blank line. I'm using Netbeans' console on Windows, but I don't think hitting ctrl+z would work here.

Comment: thanks, this does stop the reading. Thing is, it takes two blank lines to produce the output. How can I change it just to take one?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `!leido.equals(" ")`, simply use `!leido.equals("")`.  The former terminates when a line containing only a space is entered, the latter when a blank line is entered.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your problem much, but just a suggest from my side will be that use your condition in this way

```
while(!" ".equals(leido)){  
//instead of   
while (!leido.equals(" ")){
```

why ?, because your code will throw a Exception if your variable contains null, and the condition which i mentioned will never do that :P